# Dynamically add elements inside web component

Tags: javascript, web-component, native-web-component

I would like to create a web component that contains a list of elements that can be added to.
For example if I had an initial template like:

```
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `<input type="text"></input><button>add div</button>`;

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    const button = this._shadowRoot.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", this.addDiv);
  }
  addDiv(e) {
    // ...
  }
}
customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
```

and each time the button is clicked, a `<div>` is added which contains the text from the input field, thereby creating something like:

```
<input type="text"></input><button>add div</button>
<div>first text from input added</div>
<div>second text from input added</div>
...
```

Comment: This can be isolated from webcomponents. You may have tried appendChild &cie, what was the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you cannot use `insertAjacentHTML()` on the Shadow DOM `shadowRoot` property because the Shadow Root doesn't implement the Element interface.

### Use bind( this )

A better solution is to use `appendChild(`) on the `shadowRoot` property. However, you'll need to add a special [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) operation on the `click` event callback.

In an event callback, this indeed references the element that triggered the event, not the object which the callback is defined in.

In order to get the reference to the custom element (in order to access the input element in the Shadow DOM `shadowRoot`, call `bind(this)` inside `addEventListener()`.

```
button.addEventListener( "click", this.addDiv.bind( this ) )
```

See a full example below:

```js
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `<input type="text"></input><button>add div</button>`;

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this._shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    const button = this._shadowRoot.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", this.addDiv.bind( this ) );
  }
  addDiv(e) {
    var div = document.createElement( 'div' )
    div.textContent = this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'input' ).value
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild( div )
  }
}
customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

---

### Use arrow function

Another solution whould be to use an [*arrow function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). With arrow function, this is not redefined, so you don't need to use `bind()`.

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
    const sh = this.attachShadow( { mode: "open" } )
    sh.innerHTML = `<input type="text"></input><button>add div</button>`
    const button = sh.querySelector( "button" )
    button.onclick = ev => {
      let div = document.createElement( "div" )
      div.textContent = sh.querySelector( "input" ).value
      sh.appendChild( div )
    }
  }
}
customElements.define( "my-element", MyElement )
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

Comment: Is it possible to add HTML element inside Web components ?. 
Example: 
<my-element>
      <p>Test</p>
</my-element>

Comment: The paragraph is available in DOM but the content of the `<p>` is not displaying in the browser.

Please refer the image: [link] (https://imgur.com/bx5ZhKY)

Answer (score 2):

Extending on Supersharps answer:

- `attachShadow()` **sets** `this.shadowRoot` by default
- `attachShadow()` **returns** the shadowRoot, so you can chain `.innerHTML` on it
- `appendChild()` returns the appended DIV, so you can chain it

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super() // sets AND return 'this' scope
        .attachShadow({mode: "open"})
        .innerHTML = '<input type="text"></input><button>add div</button>';
    this.shadowRoot.querySelector('button').onclick = evt =>
      this.shadowRoot
          .appendChild(document.createElement("div"))
          .innerHTML = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input").value
  }
}
customElements.define("my-element", MyElement)
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

Or rewrite it to one helper function $append
which makes the rest of the code readable

```js
class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({mode: "open"});

    let $append = ( tag, html = '' ) => (
          tag = this.shadowRoot.appendChild(document.createElement(tag)),
          tag.innerHTML = html,
          tag // return tag, so onclick can be chained
        );

    let input = $append('input');
    $append('button', 'add div').onclick = evt => $append("div", input.value);
  }
}
customElements.define("my-element", MyElement)
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Danny's answer I realised I don't need to create `this._shadowRoot`, so my question and Supersharp's answer can be simplified to the below. I've kept the template because it is good practice to create web components from templates because performance is better than using `shadowRoot.innerHTML`.

```
const template = document.createElement("template");
template.innerHTML = `<input type="text"></input><button>add div</button>`;

class MyElement extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" });
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
    const button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("button");
    button.addEventListener("click", this.addDiv.bind(this));
  }
  addDiv(e) {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    div.textContent = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input").value;
    this.shadowRoot.appendChild(div);
  }
}
customElements.define("my-element", MyElement);
```

Comment: Where is the documentation for "*templates better performance*" ? **One** .innerHTML on a DOM can't be much different than **one**  appendChild (which in your code above already executed a (in memory) ``innerHTML``). The key point is your are doing **One** append in both cases. I am not going to do a JSPerf but I would dare to say your code above needs to do more CPU operations than **one** .innerHTML. And makes your code smaller and easier to read...

Comment: From Google's web components guide [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements): "Note: In the above snippet we use a template element to clone DOM, instead of setting the innerHTML of the shadowRoot. This technique cuts down on HTML parse costs because the content of the template is only parsed once, whereas calling innerHTML on the shadowRoot will parse the HTML for each instance. We'll talk more about templates in the next section."